# Dividend Leakage for European Vanguard funds

Tags: taxes, investing, index-fund

I recently stumbled upon an [article](http://jlcollinsnh.com/2014/01/27/stocks-part-xxi-investing-with-vanguard-for-europeans/) warning European investors about "dividend leakage" when investing in Vanguard funds as a European investor due to a dividend tax within Ireland from which the European Vanguard funds are based.

I'm a British/Irish dual citizen living overseas in the Netherlands. I've invested in the Vanguard Lifestrategy 80% equity fund and the Vanguard Emerging market index. Will I be subject to Irish dividend tax and is it possible to claim it back?

Comment: Hey, I'm also based in the Netherlands. Did you reach a conclusion? I think you're definitely paying dividend tax, there's no pay pack on what they withheld.

Comment: @Joel_Blum I'm afraid not unfortunately.